# Can impl bean in spring have more public methods than Interface?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

if there is an interface in spring with 1 abstract public method and an implementation of this interface with 2 public methods (1 is overide and second public method is extra). If we autowire the interface we are not able to use the second public method in impl. Is this a correct behavior? In maven build it does say its using and autowiring IMPL bean but not able to find the second extra public method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a Java question rather than a Spring one. There are a few things going on here:

1. Yes, an implementation can have more methods than the interface it's implementing.
2. Since you cannot initialize an interface, as in Spring case, it can only autowire an implementation of the interface to your bean.

Let's look at the following example:

You have an interface `SomeInterface` with methods `methodA`, and it's implementation `SomeInterfaceImpl` with `methodA` and `methodB`.

If you autowire a bean by its interface:

```
@Autowired private SomeInterface someInterface;
```

then you can only access `methodA` (without explicitly casting it to `SomeInterfaceImpl`, obviously), although what you have autowired is `SomeInterfaceImpl` and has `methodB` implemented.

If you autowire its impltementation:

```
@Autowired private SomeInterfaceImpl someInterface;
```

then you'll be able to access both `methodA` and `methodB`. HTH.

Comment: Kudos for the detailed explanation :), but would you say its a  good practice to autowire the SomeInterfaceImpl to access method b ? Is this technique used regularly by experienced spring developers for accessing methodB?

Comment: Depends on the case, but 90% of the time, it's not good practice. What's the point of having the interface if you're injecting the implementation? I had done it in the past, but as I said, it was required in that case.